# how to force rscync to unmunge symlinks

Tags: rsync, backup-restoration

I make backups with rsync (with -a) on my own rsync server, and all links are munged (added /rsync-munged/ before each symlink) - which is good

But today I need to restore my backup from rsync server and I don't know how tu unmunge it.

--munge-links doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable `munge links` option on rsync daemon and not to use `--munge-links` on client.